# Правильно ли предложение с точки зрения синтаксиса

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, деепричастия

Для сочинения, прошу помочь!
Правильно ли предложение с точки зрения синтаксиса: Наташа способна находить радость в мелочах и, **фокусируя её в своей душе, излучать во много раз больше**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

*Наташа способна находить радость в мелочах и, **наполняя светлым сиянием свою душу**, излучать во много раз больше.*